# operations on column in data frames in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, operation

I have a list of data frames. Each data frame contains information about a student's performance over various years for each subject. I want to add a column to each data frame and this column contains the change in the percentage acquired from one year to another for a specific subject (Maths) say this is the 4th column ( the one starting with 13.3793). For example, I want the new column to be 2008 value minus 2007 value. the next value being 2009 value minus 2008 value. and do this for each data frame in the list.

how can i do this?

```
3  2/28/2006             0.0300                   0.0587      13.3793      17.5165
4  2/28/2007             0.0000                   0.0687      16.3830      19.7525
5  2/29/2008             0.0443                   0.0797      28.0438      35.5054
6  2/28/2009             0.0186                   0.0944      32.7590      42.1171
7  2/28/2010             0.0186                   0.1120      46.4340     122.2340
8  6/30/2011             0.0284                   0.1136      48.1521     105.6144
9  6/30/2012             0.0484                   0.1746      70.1611     146.8783
```

Comment: Can you use `dput(variable)` to show us the structure and column names?

Answer (score 1):

For one dataframe you can subtract the 2nd row minus 1st row by using `lag` in `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(date = lubridate::mdy(date)) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(diff = Maths - lag(Maths))
```

To apply this to list of dataframes you can use `lapply` or `purrr::map`.

```
result <- lapply(list_df, function(df) df %>%
                   mutate(date = lubridate::mdy(date)) %>%
                   arrange(date) %>%
                   mutate(diff = Maths - lag(Maths)))
```

Comment: I have just tried this and it gives me an error : error/rlang_error>
Can't transform a data frame with duplicate names @ronak. I also dont think that the dates have been interpreted as dates in the dataframes, so I was thinking about a solution involving indexing but I dont know how to go about it

Comment: Well, it seems your dataframe has duplicate column names as the error suggests. Try using `janitor::clean_names()` i.e `df %>% janitor::clean_names() %>% mutate(date = ...`. Also adding a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) would is helpful.

Comment: I will post a question again with the code because it doesn't allow me to write a long comment